# Return a Stream from a deck of playing cards

Tags: java, string, list, char, java-stream

We consider a deck of playing cards in the following format:

> Ranks: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, T, J, Q, K, A
>
> Suits: S - Spade, D - Diamond, H - Heart, C - Club

Every card will be identified by 2 characters
E.g. "3S" (3 of Spades), "TC" (10 of Club), "AH" (Ace of Heart). I want to modify the `getCardsBySuit` method in order to return a `Stream` with all the cards belonging to that suit.

E.g. for a list that contains "2H", "3S", "TH" and the suit is 'H', the result should be a stream containing **"2H" and "TH"**

```
public static Stream<String> getCardsBySuit(List<String> cards, char suit) {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Step 1: create a stream from the list. Step 2: chain a filter that will let the right elements pass.

Comment: ..and for the current use case Step 3:`return` that `Stream`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all elements in cards have atleast 2 characters and the suit is at second position.

```java
return cards.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.charAt(1) == suit);
```

Please note that while using the returned stream, once you have applied any terminal operation, then you won't be able to use same stream object again. You will have to invoke this method again.